# Converting a 2D rotation matrix into a Euler angle

Tags: math

How do I convert a 2x2 rotation matrix into a Euler angle? The rotation matrix is:

```
{{.46, .89}, {.89, -.46}}
```

Wikipedia instructs me that a 2D rotation matrix takes the form:

```
{{cos(a), -sin(a)}, {sin(a), cos(a)}}
```

Knowing that

```
{{cos(a), -sin(a)}, {sin(a), cos(a)}} = {{.46, .89}, {.89, -.46}}
```

I computed

```
{{inverseCos(a), -invereSin(a)}, {invereSin(a), inverseCos(a)}}
```

to get (these values were converted to degrees)

```
{{62.3, -62.3}, {62.3, 117.8}}
```

What am I supposed to do with these numbers? Aren't they supposed to be equal? The universe no longer makes sense to me.

Comment: Where did your "rotation" matrix come from?

Comment: It came from a singular value decomposition courtesy of [wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=singularvaluedecomposition[{{.3784,+.177},{.177,.6216}}])

Comment: According to your formulas, this _can't_ be a 2D rotation matrix, since the top left and bottom right entries aren't equal, but they're always equal for a 2D rotation matrix.

Comment: that was confusing me, too. The equation is [legit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) though, as is the source of the data. I don't understand what the problem is, or how to solve it.

Comment: The point is, the problem is the math, not the Java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your matrix is not a pure rotation. The first and last entries are the negative of each other and so can't possibly both be equal to the cosine of some angle.

Looks like you actually have a scale matrix multiplied in there too of the form

```
{{1, 0}, {0, -1}}
```

**Edit:**

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition):

> In this case, the diagonal matrix Σ is uniquely determined by M (though the matrices U and V are not).

In your [wolfram example](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=singularvaluedecomposition%5B%7B%7B.3784%2C+.177%7D%2C%7B.177%2C.6216%7D%7D%5D) both U and V have a scale matrix of {{1,0},{0,-1}} in them which of course cancel out to leave pure rotation matrices. My understanding is that these would be a valid choice of U and V too i.e. the decomposition is not unique.

Comment: [Wiki says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) that the U and V matrices given in the [wolfram link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=singularvaluedecomposition.3784,+.177,.177,.6216) are rotation matrices. Can you please help me identify whats wrong here?

Comment: +1 for mentioning that this isn't rotation only. Maybe a little more in-depth theory would be useful; I'd be interested in reading about it one way or the other.

Comment: It's a sad day for stackoverflow when people start upvoting for "interesting" claims, irrespective of whether they are true. Did it never occur to you that the OP's coordinates and the formula he found use switched x and y coordinates? You know, there are different ways to label axes in a coordinate system ...

Comment: The input matrix I passed into the svd function to get the rotation matrix is taken from a [published article on ellipsoids](http://staff.polito.it/giuseppe.calafiore/Documenti/Papers/Ellipsoidal%20Approximation_TSMC-02.pdf).

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong, but can't remove the downvote anymore ... (stupid 5 minute limit)

Comment: meriton: No problem, you had me worried for a minute :) I was trying to work it through with switched co-ordinates after your comment but couldn't see how that would explain it.

Answer (score 2):

Inverse trigonometric functions return one value, but there are two such values.

```
cos(a) = cos(-a) 

sin(a) = sin(PI - a)
```

In radians, of course.

The first thing you should do is use the sign of the values to determine the quadrant you are in. Then you can calculate the real values.

The fact that cos is positive and sinus is negative means that you are dealing with angles in the fourth quadrant; between 3PI/2 (270) and 2PI(360).

Comment: In fact I answer the problem described in the text (which is different from the problem described in the title). Anyway, you seem to have a fetish with punishing people, so I forgive you (you are wellcome)

Comment: Your answer is incorrect for the problem in the text. My voting history shows clearly I have no such fetish for punishing people, quite the opposite in fact.

Answer (score 1):

> It came from a singular value decomposition courtesy of wolfram

An SVD gives you two *orthogonal* matrices (and the diagonal matrix of eigenvalues, of course). Rotation matrices aren't the only orthogonal matrices. A rotation and subsequent a "flip" (scale by -1 on one axis) is orthogonal, too. If you want to get a rotation matrix from an SVD, you have to check for a flip and flip the matrix back in that case.

Comment: "In the common case in which M is just an m×m square matrix with positive determinant whose entries are plain real numbers, then U, V*, and Σ are m×m matrices of real numbers,..., U and V* can be viewed as rotation matrices."

Comment: +1: Thanks for editing it and mentioning that the matrices are only guaranteed to be orthogonal.

Comment: @Troubadour It does look like a flip and a rotation to me - I can decompose the matrix into a flip about the X-axis followed by a rotation of 62.3°.

Comment: @hc. The [matrix M](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=singularvaluedecomposition%5B%7B%7B.3784%2C+.177%7D%2C%7B.177%2C.6216%7D%7D%5D) is positive definite. It is {{.3784, .177},{.177,.6216}} and is the argument passed into the singular value decomposition to yield the rotation matrix. The matrix I provided in the question is the rotation matrix and doesn't need to be pos/def. Thanks for looking at my question.